# Creating a graph from only the edge lengths between nodes

Tags: c++, stl, graph-theory

If there is a graph with N nodes and I'm only given a N*N matrix of the distances from each node to every other (the diagonal is of course 0), what would be the most efficient way of generating a graph with as few edges as possible?

for n = 4 and the matrix

```
0 1 2 3
1 0 3 4
2 3 0 5
3 4 5 0
```

only having 3 edges would be enough, all connected to the 1st node.

- the edge from 1 and 2 would have length 1
- the edge from 1 and 3 would have length 2
- the edge from 1 and 4 would have length 3

Comment: Is it true that the edge lengths don't actually matter?  From your description it sounds like all that matters is whether two nodes are directly connected or not.  So it's really an N*N matrix (half of which is irrelevant duplication) of booleans.  Right?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I mean the end output is which nodes are connected and the length of the edge. But the matrix has basically the shortest distances from two nodes if that makes sense

Comment: I think you should post a very simple concrete example in your question.  Like with N=4 or so.  Showing the input and the desired output and explaining why.

Comment: Not sure if there's a more efficient way to go about this than going over the all possible combinations of different nodes `a`, `b`, `c` and if `d(a,b)+d(b, c) == d(a, c)` to remove `(a, c)`

Comment: The term for further research is [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). You may be looking to compute a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). The article mentions algorithms for the same.

Comment: The answer doesn't have to be a tree so looking into minimal spanning trees will probably get you nowhere.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Why not? The result graph above seems to be undirected, so removing an edge in a cycle would reduce the number of edges without disconnecting the graph.

Comment: @beaker you cannot remove an edge if it increases the distance between the vertices.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ah, I didn't bother calculating the distances in the result. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

" N*N matrix of the distances from each node to every other (the diagonal is of course 0)"

This is called the adjacency matrix.  It completely specifies the graph.  Each non-sero value defines an edge between two vertices.  You cannot reduce the number of edges below the number of non zero value without changing the graph.

Comment: I took it to mean they want a graph with as few edges as possible while keeping all the nodes connected somehow.  But this is not very clear.

Comment: This is wrong. The matrix specifies distances between vertices along the minimal path between those vertices, not the edge lengths. So the matrix is not the adjacency matrix of the graph OP wants to build. (It is the adjacency matrix of its closure.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a full graph using the matrix as the incidence matrix, then remove unneeded edges.

Edge `(a,b)` is unneeded if and only if there is another path from `a` to `b` of the same length as `(a,b)`. That is, if there is vertex `c` different from both `a` and `b` such that

```
distance(a,b) = distance(a,c) + distance(c,b)
```

This will not work if some distances not on the diagonal are zero or negative.